# Using Custom Text and Expressions in SSRS mobile reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, datazen-server

I am currently using Datazen/SSRS mobile reports for our iphone dashboards.  I was wondering is it possible to bring in a date variable via expression for something like the subtitle in one of the gauges? Example being "Data current as of 20190101"

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but I'm not an expert on it. Mobile reports have extremely limited formatting functionality.